# elasticsearch wildcard or regex

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirement is like if I will enter any character then it should return any value containing the character e.g. *char*
How can I write optimized java code to implement the above requirement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your index mapping look like? What analyzers are you using? Try to include all relevant information please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ignore_above: 256,
index: "not_analyzed",
type: "string"
rest are default values.
I have tried with QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery() by appending * in the value. It gives the result taking value as prefix whereas my requirement is *value*